# Multilayer perceptron in scikit-learn

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, scikit-learn, multi-layer

I am trying to code a multilayer perceptron in scikit learn 0.18dev using MLPClassifier. I have used the solver lbgfs, however it gives me the warning :
ConvergenceWarning: Stochastic Optimizer: Maximum iterations reached and the optimization hasn't converged yet.
  % (), ConvergenceWarning)

How can I fix this?

Comment: increase the maximum interations?

Comment: i tried that, it doesn't help. I took the max iterations upto 200000, but still getting same warning.

Comment: what's the output like if you run it with `MLPClassifier(verbose=True)`?

Comment: Weird: if you use lbfgs you should not get a warning referring to "Stochastic Optimizer". Can you check that you still get this error on the current version of master (with `solver='lbfgs'`) and report an issue if with a minimalistic reproduction code snippet if you still experience the issue.

Comment: Actually please update your question to include a minimalistic reproduction code snippet here on stackoverlow: http://scikit-learn.org/dev/faq.html#what-s-the-best-way-to-get-help-on-scikit-learn-usage

Comment: I had the same error, and increasing the number of iterations to a substantial number solved this error in my case

Answer (score 3):

How about setting `hidden_layer_sizes` and `max_iter` parameters?

```
mlp = MLPClassifier(solver='lbfgs', hidden_layer_sizes=[100], max_iter=2000, activation='logistic')
```